# How to show appbar on draggable modal bottom sheet in flutter on full screen mode

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create a draggable modal bottom sheet, and when the user scrolls that to full screen, an app bar widget shows on top. Something like this:

[image: gif]

But I don't find any package or tutorial for doing that in flutter. Can you show me a sample, please?

Comment: can you include code-snippet that will reproduce the same error

Answer (score 0):

hey i think i might able help you but with a theoretical answer.

i think you could achieve this by not actually using the app bar instead make a check that if bottom sheet height is equal to the screen height then you can simply show a app bar type widget inside bottom sheet because back screen app bar won't be visible at that time .

Comment: How to drag a bottom sheet to the full screen?